# Translating python code to mathematica code

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, python

I am working on a program that does some stuff with the [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). I originally wrote it in Python as that is the language I am most familiar with:

```
n = []
mod = []
step = 0

def lstfill(nb,ne,lst):
    while nb <= ne:
        lst.append(nb)
        nb+=1

def collatz(n, s):
    for i in n:
        s = 0
        print "starting #", i
        while i != 1:
            if i%2==0:
                i=i/2
                s+=1
                print i
                mod.append(i%2)
            else:
                i=3*i+1
                s+=1
                print i
                mod.append(i%2)
        print "mod:", mod
        print "steps:", s

lstfill(3,6,n)
collatz(n, step)
```

However, there are some things I need to do that I can't really do without downloading libraries and I can't do that. So I thought I'd switch to Mathematica. Except I looked at my code and realized I had no idea how to write this code in the Mathematica language. How would I manipulate lists, or create functions, or anything like that? And what is the equivalent of the modulo operator?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look up `Mod[]` already? Have you also searched the site for "collatz"?

Comment: @J.M., thank you for the `Mod[]` command! I guess I kind of wanted to be able to use my own code that I wrote in Python, just translate it, and I didn't know quite how to write a function or manipulate lists.

Comment: Btw, for this application you can - and should - easily add memoization. Simulation of Collatz over a set of initial conditions will inevitably overlap previous computed values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question demonstrates one of the best things I love about *Mathematica*; mathematical notation as code.

Using <kbd>Esc</kbd>+pw+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you can enter the function in [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) mathematical notation.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or by code

```
f[n_Integer] := Piecewise[{{n/2, Mod[n, 2] == 0}, {3*n + 1, Mod[n, 2] == 1}}]
```

Then with [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) and the [Pure Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) `# != 1 &` for stopping,

```
NestWhileList[f, 8, # != 1 &]
```

> ```
> {8, 4, 2, 1}
> ```

and with an odd number start,

```
NestWhileList[f, 11, # != 1 &]
```

> ```
> {11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1}
> ```

I much prefer these two lines of code to the alternative.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's what I like about *Mathematica* too: you can often say a lot with much less. :)

Comment: @heather You can use `f[n_Integer/;Positive[n]]` to be more strict on the the integers `f` will accept. I left that out for simplicity as you are just starting.

Comment: I would've done that as `f[n_Integer?Positive]` myself. ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't realize how much *shorter* the Mathematica code would be. =) I'm now working on expanding the code and I think I get the general-ish idea of the functions and while loops, so thank you very much!

Comment: to be fair, the python version could be made a lot shorter too.